# Is it possible to infer the edit distance using a unified diff?

Tags: algorithm, bash, shell

I have 2 files with contents spanning multiple lines. I'd like to find the edit distance; i.e. how many changes are required to transform A to B assuming only insertions and deletions are possible.

```
> cat > A                                 
A
B
C
D
E
> cat > B                                 
A
B
D
D
F
E
> diff -u A B                             
--- A   2015-05-12 16:09:31.000000000 +0200
+++ B   2015-05-12 16:09:42.000000000 +0200
@@ -1,5 +1,6 @@
 A
 B
-C
 D
+D
+F
 E
```

Would it be accurate to say that the total number of `+` and `-` give me the edit distance?

Comment: Changing the contents of a line isn't allowed? What about re-ordering lines? (diff isn't always smart or optimal about which chunk of lines it thinks is "moved" in those cases.) Are you just looking for how many lines were added and removed?

Comment: Thanks. The order of the lines is important; I cant reorder them. Yes, I'm looking for the number of insertions and deletions that let me transform A->B.

Answer (score 2):

Going by your definition of edit distance (similiar to ["Longest common subsequence problem"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem)), you will first need to define what a single change is.

- a single character?
- a line?
- a file?

> The longest common subsequence problem is a classic computer science
>   problem, the basis of data comparison programs such as the `diff`
>   utility, and has applications in bioinformatics. It is also widely
>   used by revision control systems such as Git for reconciling multiple
>   changes made to a revision-controlled collection of files.

Assuming you want *lines* to define a change (based on your example), then yes, the total number of `+` and `-` using the `diff` command would suffice. This is because an update/substitution will show up as both a deletion (`-`) and an insertion (`+`).

See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff_utility#Unified_format